# Why when delete and Re-Add tables to .EDMX some tables appeared in different names?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Model I updated some tables and I need to update model from database ,

So I deleted the tables from the diagram and Re-Add again but there is something wrong with the table names its not show as there name in the database like this :

```
in the database table name                      After Re-add model name 

1-  Patients                                            Patient 

2-  LabTests                                            LabTest

3-  Customers                                           Customer
```

Why its not show like the database name

How to solve this issue and Re-Add the tables with same name in the database ?

```
public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LabTest> LabTests { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
```

I Updated the Tables names in the Model and in the file Context.cs ,

```
public virtual DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LabTests> LabTests { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Patients> Patients { get; set; }
```

but when I opened the EDMX diagram its not updated .

[image]

How to update the names also on Model.EDMX also ?

Comment: Are you talking about the Entity Type name or the `DbSet<T>` property name?  The Entity Type name should normally be singular, and the `DbSet<T>` property name plural.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes and before delete from diagram its ok but after re-add some tables show in different names

Comment: That looks like the default and recommended way.  If you want different type names, you can edit the EDMX.  The `DbSet<Customer>` conceptually maps to the database table`  `Customer` maps to a single row in that table.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I updated the the names in context.cs and models but not updated in the diagram how to update the names on context.EDMX as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old EDMX-based Database First workflow, the pluralization/singularization of entity names and entity set names is controlled at update time by the wizard setting:

[image]

And can be changed later in the Entity property pages:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much from three days I am searching and trying to solve this issue :)